# What should I write in the "Member State of first entry" field on a Schengen visa application form?

Tags: schengen, applications

Travelling to France from UK with my family and while filling in the visa application form but there is a question that needs to be answered and I am not clear what to fill in:

**Member State of first entry**  - what should be filled in here?

Flight is from UK to France (CDG) but the flight operator is KLM and it is not direct. there is a 45 min break between two flights

UK(Leeds) — Netherlands(Amsterdam) — France (Paris)

Should the answer to this question be France (Paris) or Netherlands (Amsterdam).

Answer (score 2):

The member state of first entry is the state through whose external borders you first enter the Schengen Area.

With the itinerary you describe, your first entry -- indeed your *only* entry into the Schengen Area -- will be the Netherlands. You will pass through immigration controls in Amsterdam, and your flight from Amsterdam to Paris is a Schengen-internal flight with no immigration control (save for whatever checks the French choose to do right now due to their ongoing state-of-emergency -- but that still doesn't count as an *entry* into the Schengen area).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Also if one does not leave the international zone and does not go through immigration control in Holland, then the first entry will be France. I have checked with the airline and they have confirmed that immigration control will be France

Comment: @user1226193: You won't be able to get on a plane from Amsterdam to Paris _without_ leaving the international zone in Amsterdam -- such flights depart from gates _after_ immigration control. I don't know how you got an airline person to tell you otherwise, but they must not have completely understood which itinerary you were asking about.