# Member state of First Entry

Tags: schengen

I am leaving Jamaica to go to Austria, what should I write as my entry state of  first entry? I will be leaving to study for 4 months.
Also, I am not sure what I need to write for member state (s) of destination. Should I write Austria since this is the main destination?

Comment: Are you flying direct from Jamaica to Austria?

Comment: "State of First Entry" is the country you enter the Schengen area via. Destination state is Austria.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I write in the "Member State of first entry" field on a Schengen visa application form?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67170/what-should-i-write-in-the-member-state-of-first-entry-field-on-a-schengen-vis) -- and several other similar questions in the "Related" column.